# How to Use Flask WTForms to Create Multi-Select Option

Tags: python, html, flask, flask-wtforms

I want to add a form on my webpage that lets users select multiple options (not in a dropdown list).
For example,
If there are 3 possible items, they should be listed as follows:

```
 ITEM 1                           ITEM 2                    ITEM 3
```

They should be in separate "boxes", which should be selectable. I don't want to do this in a dropdown or list view. What are my options?

Comment: Do you want Checkboxes?

Comment: No I don't. The item boxes themselves should be clickable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I would use `checkbox` with styling.  You can do this in Flask/WTF, but here is the objective:

```css
body {
  background: white;
  color: #323232;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: Helvetica neue, roboto;
}
input[type=checkbox] {
  display:none;
}

input[type=checkbox] + label {
  background: #ccc;
  font-style: italic;
  padding: 20px;
  cursor:pointer;
} 
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
  background: #f00;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<div style="inline-block">
    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" name="toggle" class="hideThis">
    <label for="toggle">Toggle</label>
</div>
<div style="inline-block">
    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle2" name="toggle2" class="hideThis">
    <label for="toggle2">Toggle</label>
</div>
<div style="inline-block">
    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle3" name="toggle3" class="hideThis">
    <label for="toggle3">Toggle</label>
</div>
```

Comment: How would I redirect the page to a different site depending on the selections? Like if there are 3 options, selecting 1,2 should go to page A, selecting 3 should go to page B, etc.

Comment: You don’t need a form to do that. You would just add onclick handlers to each div. But that is a separate question. If this answered your question, you should accept the answer and ask a separate question if needed.